# Why does my screen scroll back down after I scroll it up?

Tags: objective-c, ios, keyboard, scroll

I'm having trouble with scrolling the screen in an iPad app. In my app, there can be lots of fields near the bottom of the page. So instead of frequent adjustments to the screen position depending on the location of the currently active field, I would like for the screen to be in one of two positions: scrolled or not-scrolled. If the user is working on a field any part of which would be hidden by the keyboard, I would like to scroll the screen up by the height of the keyboard.

My problem is that after the keyboard appears and the screen scrolls the distance specified by my code, the screen then snaps back down to a position such that the cursor, wherever it happens to be, is just above the top of the keyboard. I don't understand what is causing this final snap. My scrolling code (lifted from a tutorial) is below.

Thanks

```
//Scroll the screen up if the keyboard hides the current field
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Step 1: Get the height of the keyboard.
    if ([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {
        keyboardHeight = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
    }
    else 
    {
        keyboardHeight = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.width;
    }

    // Step 2: Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
    [(UIScrollView*)[self view] setContentInset: contentInsets];
        [(UIScrollView*)[self view] setScrollIndicatorInsets: contentInsets];

    // Step 3: Scroll the screen up by the height of the keyboard.
        visibleRect = self.view.frame;
        visibleRect.size.height -= (keyboardHeight + [[self toolbar] bounds].size.height);
        if (([self.activeField frame].origin.y + [self.activeField frame].size.height) > visibleRect.size.height) 
        {
            //make sure scrolling is vertical only
            CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(currentLeftEdge, keyboardHeight);
            [(UIScrollView*)[self view]  setContentOffset: scrollPoint animated:YES];
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you changing anything else on some of the textfield delegate methods? If not,  it seems like you're not setting the scrollview's contentsize properly, so after the setContentOffset:Animated:, the scrollview just adjusts itself.

Comment: The way the docs are written says to me that the scrollview doesn't adjust itself, or have any automatic behavior. But as I play with the app more, it seems that I get this snapping behavior only on TextViews. The ScrollView is automatically adjusting itself so that the line of the TextView currently being edited is kept at the top of the keyboard. Each time the cursor goes to a new line the ScrollView scrolls up a line to keep the cursor in view. This is OK, just not what I wanted, and not described in the Apple docs I am reading. I'd like to turn this behavior off.